# confirmation box onItemSelected in Spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-dialog

I would like to show a confirmation box when the user clicks an item on the `spinner` box with options "cancel" and "ok". On "ok" it should change the `spinner item` and on "cancel" it should do nothing. I am not able to do this as `OnClickListener` doesn't work on `Spinner`. Can anybody help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class SpinnerActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
...

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
        int pos, long id) {
    // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
    // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
    // Now you can show your dialog
    // And you can set the spinner previous selected item via
    // spinnerObject.setSelection(previousIndex);
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // Another interface callback
}
```

}

You can read more about spinners here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html and here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html

Comment: how do you get the 'previousIndex' and how to response of dialog box inside onItemSelected

Comment: You can save previous index in additional variable and then manipulate with it.
Sorry, can't understand your question. What does you mean by "how to response of dialog box inside onItemSelected"?

Comment: sorry, typo. How do you get the response of dialogbox(confirmation) that user is sure or cancels the selection.

Comment: please check this link. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html
if it will be difficult to implement
i will post example code for you.